# Can't get animations to work with tailwind css

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

basically I am trying to get fade in animations to work on tailwind css through tailwind elements and via html.

```
import { Animate, initTE } from "tw-elements";
initTE({ Animate });
```

I've imported this exactly as their documentation states.: https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/content-styles/animations/#docsTabsAPI

```
<h2 id='name' data-te-animation-init data-te-animation-start="onScroll" data-te-animation-reset="true" data-te-animation="[fade-in_1s_ease-in-out]" className='text-white font-Bebas_Neue font-bold text-6xl absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-40 text-center z-10 md:text-5xl xl:text-7xl '>Alexander Zhao </h2>
```

this is one of the elements I have in my divs and the animation wont run. Is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: Important: If you want to use one of the animations above you got to add their name in object safelist in theme of your tailwind.config.js. For example: safelist: ['animate-[fade-in_1s_ease-in-out]', 'animate-[fade-in-down_1s_ease-in-out]']. I think you may miss this main point.

Comment: I've added this and the animation will still not toggle